# How to make script resize images and divs on window resize and orientation change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize

I am currently using the following javascript to resize an image to the size of it's parent, while maintaining aspect ratio and keeping the parent div square. So i have a square box with a rectangle stretched to either the max width or max height depending on orientation. This works great on first load however I cannot get the images and divs to resize on page orientation change or resize to work. Any ideas. I have tried using the `window.resize` and `window.orientation` listeners.

Original code was from:
[Scale, crop, and center an image...](https://selbie.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/scale-crop-and-center-an-image-with-correct-aspect-ratio-in-html-and-javascript/)

```
var aspHt = $('.aspectcorrect').outerWidth();
$('.aspectcorrect').css('height', aspHt + 'px').css('width', aspHt + 'px');  

function ScaleImage(srcwidth, srcheight, targetwidth, targetheight, fLetterBox) {
    var result = {
        width : 0,
        height : 0,
        fScaleToTargetWidth : true
    };

    if ((srcwidth <= 0) || (srcheight <= 0) || (targetwidth <= 0) || (targetheight <= 0)) {
        return result;
    }

    // scale to the target width
    var scaleX1 = targetwidth;
    var scaleY1 = (srcheight * targetwidth) / srcwidth;

    // scale to the target height
    var scaleX2 = (srcwidth * targetheight) / srcheight;
    var scaleY2 = targetheight;

    // now figure out which one we should use
    var fScaleOnWidth = (scaleX2 > targetwidth);
    if (fScaleOnWidth) {
        fScaleOnWidth = fLetterBox;
    } else {
        fScaleOnWidth = !fLetterBox;
    }

    if (fScaleOnWidth) {
        result.width = Math.floor(scaleX1);
        result.height = Math.floor(scaleY1);
        result.fScaleToTargetWidth = true;
    } else {
        result.width = Math.floor(scaleX2);
        result.height = Math.floor(scaleY2);
        result.fScaleToTargetWidth = false;
    }
    result.targetleft = Math.floor((targetwidth - result.width) / 2);
    result.targettop = Math.floor((targetheight - result.height) / 2);

    return result;
}

function RememberOriginalSize(img) {
    if (!img.originalsize) {
        img.originalsize = {
            width : img.width,
            height : img.height
        };
    }
}

function FixImage(fLetterBox, div, img) {

    RememberOriginalSize(img);

    var targetwidth = $(div).width();
    var targetheight = $(div).height();
    var srcwidth = img.originalsize.width;
    var srcheight = img.originalsize.height;
    var result = ScaleImage(srcwidth, srcheight, targetwidth, targetheight, fLetterBox);

    img.width = result.width;
    img.height = result.height;
    $(img).css("left", result.targetleft);
    $(img).css("top", result.targettop);
}

function FixImages(fLetterBox) {
    $("div.aspectcorrect").each(function(index, div) {
        var img = $(this).find("img").get(0);
        FixImage(fLetterBox, this, img);
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    FixImages(true);
};
```

Comment: I would help if you make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Call .resize() after $(window).resize():

```js
$(window).resize( function(){

  var height = $(window).height();
  var width = $(window).width(); 

  if(width>height) {
    // Landscape
    $("#landscape").css('display','none');
  } else {
    // Portrait
    $("#landscape").css('display','block');
    $("#landscape").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
  }
}).resize();
```

Comment: I have tried that, however it affects the images improperly because they have not loaded yet. I have to use window.onload to wait for the images to fully load before changing them

Comment: this was right in the end. Just needed to update my logic.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was missing. The first bit of javascript is setting the style of height and width. When recalling the `.outerHeight` it was still using the inline style to calculate the width, and hence not resizing the div. I simply used `.removeAttr('style')` to remove that property first and then did the resize. Working now. I simply used `$(window).on("resize", resizeDiv)` and wrapped my resizing into a function named `resizeDiv`

```
function resizeDiv() {
    var asp = $('.aspectcorrect');
    asp.removeAttr("style");
    var aspHt = asp.outerWidth();
    asp.css('height', aspHt + 'px').css('width', aspHt + 'px'); 
    FixImages(true);
}
```